# Database and database schema suddenly out of sync

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have (I think) a very strange problem.

I have a web server running an ASP.NET MVC app querying a SQL Server database. It has all been constructed using code-first approach.

It has been working without problems for a long time, and whenever I have needed e.g. a new column in a table, I  have added the needed class to the model in question. Then I have run `Add-migration 'Migration_Name'`, and a script has been generating with the proposed changes, and after running `update-database`, the changes have been applied to the database. Easy and always working.

Yesterday, without making any changes to the database or the models (and by the way not even updating the web-server) it stopped working.

The database throws an error the moment the web-app tries to access the database

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'

The content of the database is intact I can see from browsing it from within Visual Studio.

If I run the `add-migration` command, a script is generated for every single table, column, foreign key etc for the entire database, as if the database did not contain a single one of the classes defined in the models.

So it seems that the database is not in sync with my code first models anymore. I got my IT department to copy the entire database to a test server to try to test what is wrong without messing up the production database, and after trying to run the "strange" migration script by using the update-database command, I get the same error:

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'

and it shows me that it fails when trying to create the first table in the migration script. This is not surprising, since it already exists in the database. But what is going on - I am at a loss!

So can anyone tell me might have happened here, and more importantly, how to fix it?

All the best
Troels

Comment: Sounds like you are running the migration on the wrong database. You shouldn't be trying to create table in the master database.

Comment: _without making any changes to the database or the models (and by the way not even updating the web-server)_:  This statement is the first clue that changes were made. Maybe you were hacked. Plausible deniability.

Comment: #Sean Lange: I am absolutely certain that I am running the migration on the correct database. So it cant' be the eproblem. /Troels

Comment: You might look at your migration script. The error message says you are trying to create tables in the master database which is unusual. I have seen our developers do that on accident in the past.